# Performance Impact of Generating 100's of Dynamic Methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, code-generation

What are the performance issues associated with generating 100's of dynamic methods in Ruby?

I've been interested in using the [Ruby Preferences Gem](http://github.com/pluginaweek/preferences) and noticed that it generates a bunch of helper methods for each preference you set.

For instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  preference :hot_salsa
end
```

...generates something like:

```
user.prefers_hot_salsa?         # => false
user.prefers_hot_salsa          # => false
```

If there are 100's of preferences like this, how does this impact the application?  I assume it's not really a big deal but I'm just wondering, theoretically.

Comment: You could test it and then know practically :-) Since these are (normally) done 'at startup' (when the class statement is executed) it is only a one-time creation cost.

Comment: pst is right, it's probably only a one-time cost (Memory and Startup time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every Ruby program does this sort of thing like crazy — this is what the standard `attr_` family of methods do, which are used with impunity in pretty much every Ruby program ever. Many programs also do this in other places — it's incredibly common with `method_missing` hacks, for instance. I've never timed to see exactly how it performs, but it's common enough that if it were a significant problem, it should have been noticed by now.